# Animating a CALayer shadowpath

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I'm animating the shadow path for `CALayer`.

The frame resizes correctly, but the shadow does not scale.

Instead the shadow starts at the final size `CGSize(20,20)` and holds throughout the animation even though I set the shadowPath to an initial value

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration: 0];
[CATransaction setDisableActions: TRUE];
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,10,10);
    layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds].CGPath;
[CATransaction commit];

[CATransaction begin];

    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,20);
    layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:tile.bounds].CGPath;

[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At first, small square with drop shadow.

[image: ss]

When button pushed, square and shadow grow bigger together.

[image: ss]

The main code is below:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5.0];
CAMediaTimingFunction *timing = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:timing];
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
[CATransaction commit];    

CABasicAnimation *shadowAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowPath"];
shadowAnimation.duration = 5.0;
shadowAnimation.fromValue = (id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)].CGPath;
shadowAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)].CGPath;
[layer addAnimation:shadowAnimation forKey:@"shadow"];
```

You can download this project from GitHub and just run it.

https://github.com/weed/p120812_CALayerShadowTest

This question was very hard for me !   :)

Comment: thanks for the effort.  can you tell me why my solution doesn't work?  why can you animate the frame but not the shadow path?

Comment: The point of shadow animation is to set `animationWithKeyPath` as `@"shadowPath"`. This means the object of animation is `shadowPath`. I also didn't know this mechanism, but the setting `animationWithKeyPath` is very important to make animation. Is this OK ?

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to add another answer based on Weed's answer. I took weed's answer and tried to put everything in a CATransaction because i wanted to animate multiple layers and be sure animations happened together.  Here you guys go if you ever need it.  Also, i still don't understand why you have to use the fromValue and toValue in a CATransaction.  Why can't you just do the same thing you do with other properties like frame.

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setValue:[CAMediaTimingFunction
    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]
    forKey:kCATransactionAnimationTimingFunction];

for (CALayer *layer in self.layers){
    CABasicAnimation *shadowAnimation =
    [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowPath"];

    shadowAnimation.fromValue =
        (id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds].CGPath;
    shadowAnimation.timingFunction =
        [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    layer.frame = rectFinal;
    shadowAnimation.toValue =
        (id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds].CGPath;
    layer.shadowPath =
        [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds].CGPath;
    [layer addAnimation:shadowAnimation forKey:nil];
}         
[CATransaction commit];
```